# use Kal in swift for ios

Tags: ios, swift, kal

I'm trying to add a month view calendar in my project for ios, I downloaded the `Kal library`.

I followed the instructions to add it in, my steps are:

1. add Kal folder in my project folder
2. add kal.xcodeproj file in my project by setting the location `Relative to Project`
3. click on my project, under the `General tab`, add `libkal.a` in `Linked Frameworks and libraries`
4. under `Build Phases`, add `Kal` in `Target Dependencies`
5. add `kal.bundle` in my project by setting location Relative to Project
6. in `Header Search Paths` cancel what I had, and add the `src` directory by dragging the folder in the  blank container
7. in `Other linker flags` double click multiple values and add `-all_load`
8. in my `bridging-header.h` file add `#import "Kal.h"`

I run the project, I found `Failed kal.h file not found`

What is going wrong? What should I do? Please help.

Thank you.

Comment: Kal is no longer maintained and hasn't been updated for years. It still has iOS6 look and feel. I suggest using another library.

Comment: Could you suggest me one library? I have no idea what else I can use.

Comment: JTCalendar looks fine: https://github.com/jonathantribouharet/JTCalendar. Other candidates from CocoaControls: https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=calendar. In general you should use a library which is actively maintained and has iOS 7 look and feel.

Comment: Thank you! I'm going to try it right now.

Comment: with cocoaPods I add this library(jtcalendar), but two views that I add for menu and content view with their classes in identity inspector, I have an exception Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'CALayerInvalidGeometry', reason: 'CALayer position contains NaN: [nan 25]'

Comment: Please ask a new question. Include your code and screens from a Storyboard / .xib file if needed. This way you can get better answers.